# numba jitclass - attribute a.x is a.x returns False

Tags: python, identity, jit, numba

Trying to check the identity of two jitclass instances attributes, I found this strange behaviour compared to ordinary python classes. Numba jitclass return False on its own instance attribute identity check where ordinary python classes work as expected.

```
import numba

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

spec = [('x', numba.double)]
@numba.jitclass(spec)
class MyJitClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a = MyClass(1)
b = MyJitClass(1)
```

Now checking the identity:

```
>>> a.x is a.x
True
>>> b.x is b.x
False
```

Any idea why this happens? And how I should check whether two jitclass attributes reference to the same object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me start with quoting the [`jitclass` documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html):

> The data of a jitclass instance is allocated on the heap as a C-compatible structure so that any compiled functions can have direct access to the underlying data, bypassing the interpreter.

This means the data of the class (`x` in this case) are not directly accessible by the Python interpreter. However, a transparent solution to solve this problem is to use [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/3005167). Numba seems to have taken this approach.

Every time you access `b.x`, under the hood a function is invoked that returns a Python object wrapping the value of `x`. The class does not store the object, so each access to `x` returns a new object. Verify this by calling `id(b.x)` - it will return a different ID every time.

We can simulate the behavior of the jit class with this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return float(self._x)
```

> And how I should check whether two jitclass attributes reference to the same object?

Well, they don't. The jitclass attributes don't store objects, just data.

Comment: That's really a great answer!

Comment: Glad it was useful :)